# Purchased software usage and multiple computers

Tags: software-center

Question: If I buy a program on one computer, am I allowed to use it on both my personal computers?

---

Info: So I'm dyslexic and a college student. This means that I cannot read very quickly and have to read a lot for classes. To help me the academic support center gives me audio recording of my books. The problem is that these are all DRMed. The only way I can read them is to use windows media player in windows (tried wine with no success). This is ok when I'm on my desktop which i have duel booted into windows XP and Ubuntu. But on my laptop, which I use when I'm in the library for example, I only have Ubuntu. The for purchase package "Fluendo" (Which now that I look at it I realize is Latin for "Deserving to flow") looks like it should allow me to get around these DRM issues and be able to read my texts more than just at my desktop.

But it raises two questions for me. One, if I buy this, can I install it on both my laptop and desktop? two, if I have to reformat my system, how do I recover this software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install your purchased software on your notebook and desktop.

In Ubuntu software center there is a function to reinstall previous purchase.

I made a screnshot, it's in italian but the menu item is in the same position:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn7qj3ij05kvc0f/Selezione_010.png

Then you have to log in with your ubuntu one account!

Edit: see that page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#commercial-reinstalling

P.S. you have to scroll the page to see what do you want!

Comment: ah exactly. thank you. I didn't want to have to spend 70$ to put it on both my computers. This is wonderful! Also, as you may have noticed my question, I speak Latin, so I actually could understand most of what the menu said in Italian. ^_^

Comment: i didn't read well that part! i also study latin but here in italy we start studyng it from high school and it's so boring!